# Typescript props and theming with CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, css-modules

I'm creating a react component library with typescript using CSS Modules to make the project simple but I'm struggling with typescript interfaces when it comes to theming.
I want to have several variants of my component to the user just change the property for what he wants.

Without the CSS Modules, using just SCSS for example, I can make it work when I add the prop className = `${styles.theme}` but when I change to the Modules, it stops work, it wont regonize anymore the interface properties from the Button.

Like this (Button.tsx):

```
import styles from "./Button.module.scss";
export interface ButtonProps {
  /**
   * Set this to change button theme properties
   * @default primary
   */
  theme:| "primary"
    | "info"
    | "success"
    | "warning"
    | "danger"
    | "disabled"
    | "primary-outline"
    | "info-outline"
    | "success-outline"
    | "warning-outline"
    | "danger-outline"
    | "primary-flat";
    onClick?: () => void;
}

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ 
  children, 
  onClick, 
  theme, 
  ...rest 
}) => (
  <div>
    <button 
      className={`${styles.$theme}`} 
      onClick={onClick} 
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

And the CSS Module file (Button.module.scss):

```
button {
  position: relative;
  height: 1.75rem;
  padding: 0.05rem .75rem;

  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;

  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;

  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in 0s, border-color 200ms ease-in 0s, background-color 200ms ease-in 0s, filter 200ms ease-in 0s;
}

.primary {
  background-color: $snow-04;
  border-color: $snow-04;
  color: $polar-night-04;
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%);
  }
}

.info {
  background-color: $frost-02;
  color: $polar-night-01;
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%);
  }
}
```

What can I do to have access to the theme props and others from the Button interface?
How can I syntax the className on my component to do so?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `styles.$theme` sounds like this is a typo? The destructuring assignment on props uses `theme` (without the leading `$` sign). Should be `styles.theme` instead based on the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles is an object after all... you can access the property theme like:

```js
<button className={styles[theme]} onClick={onClick} {...rest}>
  {children}
</button>
```

I just tried here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typed-css-modules-8itfp?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks so much, I was struggling to find the right syntax to make the access for that object.